# ASP.NET Core WebAPI crashes because I don't have StaticFileMiddleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm trying to build a simple WebAPI serving JSON data to a web app, but for some reason every call ends in not finding anything and instead crashing.

I have a controller with a route:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Players")]
public class PlayersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{name}", Name = "GetPlayer")]
    public Player Get(string name)
    {
        return playerService.GetPlayer(name);
    }
```

The playerservice method simply returns a dto. Unfortunately, this endpoint isn't even called.
The request pipeline gets called, and afterwards crashes with `System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware..ctor`, although I'm not even trying to get any static files, just `/api/players/dummy` or `/swagger`, none work. The call stack here is just Program.Main and then external code.

ConfigureServices goes

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v1" }));

services.AddControllers();
```

Configure goes

```
app.UseSwagger()
    .UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"))
    .UseRouting()
    .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

**Is my pipeline configured incorrectly? Do I need some static file middleware although I don't even serve static files? What am I doing wrong?**

Edit: Screenshot of the exception:
[image]

Here's the stacktrace from the exception, it seems it happens in swagger:

```
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.CreateStaticFileMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, SwaggerUIOptions options)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.<StartAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Teambuilder_WebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Sources\Teambuilder\Teambuilder WebAPI\Program.cs:line 11
```

Comment: What's the call stack on that MissingMethodException?

Comment: The call stack is literally just `Program.Main` and then [External code]. I updated the question.

Comment: Ah I'm afraid I misunderstood. I'll get the stacktrace from within the exception, just a moment.

Comment: Is this Github issue related to your problem? [Asp.net core 3.0 + Swash Buckle 5 rc1 issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1088)

Comment: or this: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1275

Comment: Oh it seems indeed I need to upgrade to version 5, since v4 simply doesnt work with coreFx 3.1. Will report back in a minute. Put it in an answer, and I can accept it when it works :)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani You solved this, thanks! It was so simple in the end :D. Post that as an answer, and I will accept it as solution.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller updating to 5.0.0-rc2 (I think there is 5.0.0-rc5 too) solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 5 of [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) package is in pre-release stage and having issue is expected.

As OP confirmed, [this github issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1088) is related to this problem, so solution would be updating to latest version.

**Update**: As OP confirmed, you can use latest stable version of Swashbuckle *v4.0.1* with .Net Core v3.1 and you are good to go.

Comment: This solved the Problem, as I updated from coreFx 2.2 to 3.1 but kept Swashbuckle on 4.0.1 as that is its latest stable version.

Comment: @Squirrelkiller thanks for the information and helping other developers, I just updated my answer to add this information.